# Why 2x insmod part_msdos in grub.cfg?

Tags: grub2

I implemented a raid 1 into a running system. Everything works fine. But after the raid install my grub.cfg got two "insmod part_msdos". Why and can I change this?

Part of my grub.cfg (generated with update-grub)

```
load_video
insmod gfxterm
insmod raid
insmod mdraid1x
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
```

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Because I want a stable system and I want to understand this. 
I don't understand it at the moment and so I don't know if it will break the system someday or maybe slow down anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a part of the update-grub scripts that does a probe of each of the disks in your raid and inserts a partition module for each one.  It doesn't do any deduping.